# GWT & HTML5 Video in Mobile Safari

Tags: gwt, video, html, mobile-safari

I'm trying to code a site in GWT that plays videos with HTML5. Everything works great on the desktop, but mobile Safari on both the iPhone and iPad do not play the video.

I can play a video using [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html).  I've even copied the code to my own plain HTML page, and it works flawlessly. If I serve that same code via a GWT widget, mobile safari will not play the video.  On the iPhone I see a gray box with a prohibitory sign around the play button, and on the iPad it shows up as a black box.

I've made sure my doctype is `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but I don't know where else to start debugging.  Perhaps it it because the code is injected via javascript?  Any pointers on where to start looking would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the exact code I am using for the video:

```
<!-- "Video For Everybody" by Kroc Camen. see <camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody> for documented code
     =================================================================================================================== -->
<video width="640" height="360" poster="poster.jpg" controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg"></source>
    <!--[if gt IE 6]>
    <object width="640" height="375" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"><!
    [endif]--><!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <object width="640" height="375" type="video/quicktime" data="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="src" value="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
    <param name="showlogo" value="false" />
    <object width="640" height="384" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="player.swf?autostart=true&amp;image=poster.jpg&amp;file=http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
        <param name="movie" value="player.swf?autostart=true&amp;image=poster.jpg&amp;file=http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" />
        <!-- fallback image -->
        <img src="poster.jpg" width="640" height="360" alt="Big Buck Bunny"
             title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object><!--[if gt IE 6]><!-->
    </object><!--<![endif]-->
</video>
```

**EDIT:**

I coppied the source that was being displayed on my iPhone/iPad using [this bookmarklet](http://fettig.net/weblog/2007/07/02/view-source-for-safari-on-iphone/).  I then copied that code to a plain HTML page, which works flawlessly.  It must have something to do with the video tag being generated via javascript. (I.E. I click on a button and the video tag is generated without a page refresh.)

I'm not sure if the issue is mobile safari, or the javascript GWT generates, but either way I'll have to find a workaround.

**EDIT (7/23/10):**

I've come back and re-visited the issue.  Since I posted the question, I've completely changed the layout of the page to use LayoutPanels instead of DockPanels and Vertical/Horizontal panels.  I've also upgraded to GWT 2.0.4.  Using an iPad with iOS 3.2.1 it still does not play video, but I do get the poster frame when I specify it (same as before).  With an iPhone 4 and iOS 4.0.1, the video plays without issue. So it looks like whatever the issue is, it's fixed with iOS 4.

Comment: hey, are you using UiBinder ?

Comment: i did the implementation and was stuck with playing the same in ipad. now i found that its an issue related to my server.

Answer (score 6):

OK I have been trying to figure this out as well. I can get the HTML5 video to work in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, just not mobile Safari for my iPad or iPhone.

My question to you guys is, how are you are you guys serving up the movie files? Have you guys read this page?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html

It talks about a segmenter to send the movie in seperate bits of data. Notice how they suggest to send the file...

```
<video src="http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8">
    This browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Also, you might want to check out

http://www.ioncannon.net/projects/http-live-video-stream-segmenter-and-distributor/

http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/1015/ipad-streaming-video-and-more/

http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/

**EDIT**

One more link, this one totally helped me figure out my problem. See we using nginx and unicorn to run our Rails site. Unfortunately nginx does not support byte-range requests, but apache does. So I tested this out on Apache and it worked. Here is the article I used as a reference to figure this out.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html

note this line of code

```
curl --range 0-99 http://example.com/test.mov -o /dev/null
```

You can use that to see if your server supports byte-range requests.

Answer (score 1):

GXT isn't the right solution.
You have to detect that your browser is mobile safari. see the right way to detect [mobile browsers in GWT](http://development.lombardi.com/?p=1282) and then create a widget that wraps the video tag.

Comment: I did create a GWT widget that wraps the video tag.  The code in my question is coming from a widget.

Comment: I think the problem comes from Flash because iPad and iPhone don't support it. You should create a GWT Video widget that uses a VideoImpl generic HTML5 implementation and another VideoImplFlash (extending VideoImpl) Flash implementation for non HTML5 browsers. The choice of the implementation will be made by GWT browser detectionmecanism using deffered binding.
See com.google.gwt.user.TextBox.gwt.xml com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBoxBase.java, com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.TextBoxImpl.java and com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.TextBoxImplIE6.java for example in GWT code

Comment: even using the widget to wrap just the video tag results in the same problem

Comment: Did you try to see the video on the iPhone in a simple HTML page (not GWT generated)? Sometimes you can have issues on videos in HTML5 because of frame rate or other things like that.

Comment: I did use a simple HTML page, even one that serves up the same code as my GWT generated page.  See my edited question.

Comment: If your GWT version works on Desktop browsers, it is not a GWT issue, but a browser (safari mobile) issue.
Did your video play on iPhone with a simple HTML page containing only :
<video width="640" height="360" poster="poster.jpg" controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
If it works you have to create an VideoImplIPhone that generates a simple video tag like above.

Comment: I did create a widget with JUST the video tag.  Same issue, doesn't play on either device.  It will play however if that code is on a plain HTML page.

Comment: As I don't have an iPhone, I can't help you more on Iphone/iPad problem, but I think you can read the AKAMAI white paper on Video for iPhone delivery. They explain lots of things on iPhone video support (about Video encoding and BitRates)
www.akamai.com/dl/akamai/iphone_wp.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As I said before in my comment from Apr 21, iPhone, iPad and all i... don't support Flash, and won'tever support it.
But iPhone OS 3.0 support HTML5 video Tag as you can read it in this [article](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/exploring-html-5-media-elements-iphone-safari-web-pages) and see it in this [one](http://www.iphon.fr/post/2010/01/27/D%C3%A9monstration-de-vid%C3%A9o-sur-iPhone-via-du-HTML5)

[AKAMAI](http://iphone.akamai.com/) is a video provider and the iPhone page uses HTML5 video tag.

iPhone supports only mp4 videos or AAC audio files.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works on my iPhone (please ignore the `GxtSandbox` part of the package name, no GXT stuff is being used, as you can see). I have a page hosted at http://binarymuse.net/video/GxtSandbox.html that you may visit on your mobile device for testing.

```
package net.binarymuse.gwt.gxt.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;

public class GxtSandbox implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        DialogBox box = new DialogBox(true);
            box.setWidget(new HTML("<video width='640' height='360' poster='poster.jpg' controls autoplay>" +
            "<source src='http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4' type='video/mp4'></source>" +
            "</video>"));
        box.center();
    }
}
```

The gray box with the prohibitory sign displays when you try to use the .ogv file as the source--perhaps Mobile Safari is trying to use that for some reason?

I would recommend creating some GWT classes that use deferred binding to create the right tag for the browser permutation being compiled. You may also find something at useful at [gwt-html5-media](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-html5-media/).

Comment: I tested that link on an iPad. Same problem with the black box. It does work on my iPhone however.  I've even cut down my code to just the video tag with the mp4 source, and I still have the same issue on both the iPhone and iPad. I'll take a look at that second link and see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

To support other HTML5 features, you can also see the [GWT-Mobile-Webkit project](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/).

Answer (score 0):

I see you have

```
<object width="640" height="384" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
```

in your code.

**The apple mobile products minus the laptop do not support flash.**

(which is the dumbest thing I have ever seen, I bet Apple is going to disallow air and water in there next license agreement.)

Also try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

if your are using html 5

Comment: Also, HTML 5 is not available till iPhone OS 4.0

Comment: HTML 5 videos have been supported since iPhone OS 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Answered thread already, but I did find this:

DO NOT INCLUDE THE poster ATTRIBUTE () FOR iPad / iPhone 3.x SUPPORT. There is a major bug with iPhone OS 3 that means that playback will not work on any HTML5 video tag that uses both the poster attribute and  elements. This was fixed in iPhone OS 4.0, but of course for now there will still be a large number of OS 3 users. This bug does not affect use of the poster image in the flashvars parameter, which you should retain.